# Send Data From Arduino to Android App via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, processing, data-transfer

Hello i can send data from android to arduino but i cant send data from arduino to android via Bluetooth on procesing i dont get any Error but I cant see anything on display of android app.. i used for blueToothSerial.print(XXX); for arduino side .. and used text(readMessage , width,heigth); for processing side. 
Please check it out . Where is my fault ? . What am I missing ? 
Thanks in Advance

**** on arduino side****

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Stepper.h>
#define RxD 6 // This is the pin that the Bluetooth (BT_TX) will transmit to the Arduino (RxD)
#define TxD 7 // This is the pin that the Bluetooth (BT_RX) will receive from the Arduino (TxD)
#define DEBUG_ENABLED 1
#define RELAY 4

SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD, TxD);  
int led = 9 ;
int in1Pin = 10;
int in2Pin = 12;
int in3Pin = 11;
int in4Pin = 13;
data = 100;
Stepper motor(512, in1Pin, in2Pin, in3Pin, in4Pin);  
/*----------------------SETUP----------------------------*/
void setup() { 



Serial.begin(9600);//low Serial communication via USB cable to computer (if required)
pinMode(RxD, INPUT); // Setup the Arduino to receive INPUT from the bluetooth shield on Digital Pin 6
pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT); // Setup the Arduino to send data (OUTPUT) to the bluetooth shield on Digital Pin 7
pinMode(13, OUTPUT); // Use onboard LED if required.
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
 motor.setSpeed(30);
 pinMode(RELAY,OUTPUT);
setupBlueToothConnection(); //Used to initialise the Bluetooth shield


} 


/*----------------------LOOP----------------------------*/
void loop() { 
digitalWrite(13, LOW); //Turn off the onboard Arduino LED
char recvChar;
while (1) {
if (blueToothSerial.available()) {//check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
recvChar = blueToothSerial.read();
Serial.print(recvChar); // Print the character received to the Serial Monitor (if required)

//If the character received = 'r' , then change the RGB led to display a RED colour
if (recvChar=='r') {
    motor.step(300);
    digitalWrite(led,HIGH);23


delay(500);

}

//If the character received = 'g' , then change the RGB led to display a GREEN colour
if (recvChar=='g') {
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  motor.step(-300);


}

//If the character received = 'b' , then change the RGB led to display a BLUE colour
if (recvChar=='b') {

digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
 digitalWrite(RELAY,HIGH);
}

//If the character received = 'x' , then turn RGB led OFF
if (recvChar=='x') {
digitalWrite(led,LOW);
 digitalWrite(RELAY,LOW);
}
}

//You can use the following code to deal with any information coming from the Computer (serial monitor)
if (Serial.available()) {
recvChar = Serial.read();

//This will send value obtained (recvChar) to the phone. The value will be displayed on the phone.
blueToothSerial.print(recvChar);
blueToothSerial.print("burak:");
blueToothSerial.print(data); // data which is defined begin of sketch

}
}
} 



//The following code is necessary to setup the bluetooth shield ------copy and paste----------------
void setupBlueToothConnection()
{
blueToothSerial.begin(9600);// BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); //set the bluetooth work in slave mode
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=HC-05\r\n"); //set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave"
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); // Permit Paired device to connect me
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n"); // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
delay(2000); // This delay is required.
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n"); //make the slave bluetooth inquirable 
Serial.println("The slave bluetooth is inquirable!");
delay(2000); // This delay is required.
blueToothSerial.flush();
}
```

And i have processing sketch .

***on processing side ***

```
/* BluetoothApp1: Written by ScottC on 25 March 2013 using 
 Processing version 2.0b8
 Tested on a Samsung Galaxy SII, with Android version 2.3.4
 Android ADK - API 10 SDK platform
 Apwidgets version: r44 */

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import apwidgets.*;
public BluetoothSocket scSocket;


//Used for the GUI**************************************
APWidgetContainer widgetContainer; 
APButton redButton, greenButton, blueButton, offButton,yeniButton;
String buttonText="";
int buttonWidth=0;
int buttonHeight=0;
int n=4; //number of buttons
int gap=10; //gap between buttons

boolean foundDevice=false; //When true, the screen turns green.
boolean BTisConnected=false; //When true, the screen turns purple.
String serverName = "ArduinoBasicsServer";

// Message types used by the Handler
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
String readMessage="";

//Used to send bytes to the Arduino
SendReceiveBytes sendReceiveBT=null;

//Get the default Bluetooth adapter
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

/*The startActivityForResult() within setup() launches an 
 Activity which is used to request the user to turn Bluetooth on. 
 The following onActivityResult() method is called when this 
 Activity exits. */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode==0) {
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 ToastMaster("Bluetooth simdi acildi");
 } 
 else {
 ToastMaster("Programi kullanabilmek icin Bluetoot acmalisiniz!!!");
 }
 }
}


/* Create a BroadcastReceiver that will later be used to 
 receive the names of Bluetooth devices in range. */
BroadcastReceiver myDiscoverer = new myOwnBroadcastReceiver();


/* Create a BroadcastReceiver that will later be used to
 identify if the Bluetooth device is connected */
BroadcastReceiver checkIsConnected = new myOwnBroadcastReceiver();



// The Handler that gets information back from the Socket
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
 switch (msg.what) {
 case MESSAGE_WRITE:
 //Do something when writing
 break;
 case MESSAGE_READ:
 //Get the bytes from the msg.obj
 byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
 // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
 readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
 break;
 }
 }
};



void setup() {
 orientation(LANDSCAPE);

 //Setup GUI********************************
 buttonWidth=((width/n)-(n*gap));
 buttonHeight=(height/2);
 widgetContainer = new APWidgetContainer(this); //create new container for widgets
 yeniButton = new APButton(700,600,(buttonWidth/2),(buttonHeight/2),"Yeni buton");
  redButton =new APButton(0,0 ,400,400, "PERDE YUKARI"); //Create a RED button
// redButton =new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-4)+(gap*1)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "RED"); //Create a RED button
 greenButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-3)+(gap*2)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "GREEN"); //Create a GREEN button
 blueButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-2)+(gap*3)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "BLUE"); //Create a BLUE button
 offButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-1)+(gap*4)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "OFF"); //Create a OFF button
 widgetContainer.addWidget(redButton); //place red button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(greenButton); //place green button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(blueButton);//place blue button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(offButton);//place off button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(yeniButton);
 background(0); //Start with a black background


 /*IF Bluetooth is NOT enabled, then ask user permission to enable it */
 if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
 Intent requestBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
 startActivityForResult(requestBluetooth, 0);
 }

 /*If Bluetooth is now enabled, then register a broadcastReceiver to report any
 discovered Bluetooth devices, and then start discovering */
 if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
 registerReceiver(myDiscoverer, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
 registerReceiver(checkIsConnected, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));

 //Start bluetooth discovery if it is not doing so already
 if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()) {
 bluetooth.startDiscovery();
 }
 }
}


void draw() {
 //Display a green screen if a device has been found,
 //Display a purple screen when a connection is made to the device
 if (foundDevice) {
 if (BTisConnected) {
 background(170, 50, 255); // purple screen
 }
 else {
 background(10, 255, 10); // green screen
 }
 }


 //Change the text based on the button being pressed.
 text(buttonText, 10, buttonHeight+(buttonHeight/2));

 //Display anything received from Arduino
 text(readMessage, 10, buttonHeight+(buttonHeight/2)+30);
}



/* This BroadcastReceiver will display discovered Bluetooth devices */
public class myOwnBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 ConnectToBluetooth connectBT;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 String action=intent.getAction();
 ToastMaster("Eylem:" + action);

 //Notification that BluetoothDevice is FOUND
 if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
 //Display the name of the discovered device
 String discoveredDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
 ToastMaster("Bulunan Cihaz: " + discoveredDeviceName);

 //Display more information about the discovered device
 BluetoothDevice discoveredDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
 ToastMaster("getAddress() = " + discoveredDevice.getAddress());
 ToastMaster("getName() = " + discoveredDevice.getName());

 int bondyState=discoveredDevice.getBondState();
 ToastMaster("getBondState() = " + bondyState);

 String mybondState;
 switch(bondyState) {
 case 10: 
 mybondState="BOND_NONE";
 break;
 case 11: 
 mybondState="BOND_BONDING";
 break;
 case 12: 
 mybondState="BOND_BONDED";
 break;
 default: 
 mybondState="INVALID BOND STATE";
 break;
 }
 ToastMaster("getBondState() = " + mybondState);

 //Change foundDevice to true which will make the screen turn green
 foundDevice=true;

 //Connect to the discovered bluetooth device (SeeedBTSlave)
 if (discoveredDeviceName.equals("HC-05")) {
 ToastMaster("BAGLANIYOR!!");
 unregisterReceiver(myDiscoverer);
 connectBT = new ConnectToBluetooth(discoveredDevice);
 //Connect to the the device in a new thread
 new Thread(connectBT).start();
 }
 }

 //Notification if bluetooth device is connected
 if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
 ToastMaster("CIHAZINIZ BAGLANDI");
 int counter=0;
 while (scSocket==null) {
 //do nothing
 }
 ToastMaster("scSocket" + scSocket);
 BTisConnected=true; //turn screen purple 
 if (scSocket!=null) {
 sendReceiveBT = new SendReceiveBytes(scSocket);
 new Thread(sendReceiveBT).start();
 String red = "r";
 byte[] myByte = stringToBytesUTFCustom(red);
 sendReceiveBT.write(myByte);
 }
 }
 }
}

public static byte[] stringToBytesUTFCustom(String str) {
 char[] buffer = str.toCharArray();
 byte[] b = new byte[buffer.length << 1];
 for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
 int bpos = i << 1;
 b[bpos] = (byte) ((buffer[i]&0xFF00)>>8);
 b[bpos + 1] = (byte) (buffer[i]&0x00FF);
 }
 return b;
}

public class ConnectToBluetooth implements Runnable {
 private BluetoothDevice btShield;
 private BluetoothSocket mySocket = null;
 private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

 public ConnectToBluetooth(BluetoothDevice bluetoothShield) {
 btShield = bluetoothShield;
 try {
 mySocket = btShield.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
 }
 catch(IOException createSocketException) {
 //Problem with creating a socket
 Log.e("ConnectToBluetooth", "Error with Socket");
 }
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
 /* Cancel discovery on Bluetooth Adapter to prevent slow connection */
 bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();

 try {
 /*Connect to the bluetoothShield through the Socket. This will block
 until it succeeds or throws an IOException */
 mySocket.connect();
 scSocket=mySocket;
 } 
 catch (IOException connectException) {
 Log.e("ConnectToBluetooth", "Error with Socket Connection");
 try {
 mySocket.close(); //try to close the socket
 }
 catch(IOException closeException) {
 }
 return;
 }
 }

 // Will allow you to get the socket from this class
 public BluetoothSocket getSocket() {
 return mySocket;
 }

 /* Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
 public void cancel() {
 try {
 mySocket.close();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
 }
 }
}



private class SendReceiveBytes implements Runnable {
 private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
 private InputStream btInputStream = null;
 ;
 private OutputStream btOutputStream = null;
 String TAG = "SendReceiveBytes";

 public SendReceiveBytes(BluetoothSocket socket) {
 btSocket = socket;
 try {
 btInputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
 btOutputStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
 } 
 catch (IOException streamError) { 
 Log.e(TAG, "Error when getting input or output Stream");
 }
 }

 public void run() {
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
 int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

 // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
 while (true) {
 try {
 // Read from the InputStream
 bytes = btInputStream.read(buffer);
 // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
 mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
 .sendToTarget();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
 Log.e(TAG, "Error reading from btInputStream");
 break;
 }
 }
 }

 /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
 public void write(byte[] bytes) {
 try {
 btOutputStream.write(bytes);
 } 
 catch (IOException e) { 
 Log.e(TAG, "Error when writing to btOutputStream");
 }
 }

 /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
 public void cancel() {
 try {
 btSocket.close();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) { 
 Log.e(TAG, "Error when closing the btSocket");
 }
 }
}



/* My ToastMaster function to display a messageBox on the screen */
void ToastMaster(String textToDisplay) {
 Toast myMessage = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
 textToDisplay, 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 myMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
 myMessage.show();
}




//onClickWidget is called when a widget is clicked/touched
void onClickWidget(APWidget widget) {
 String sendLetter = "";

 //Disable the previous Background colour changers
 foundDevice=false;
 BTisConnected=false;

 if (widget == redButton) { //if the red button was clicked
 buttonText="RED";
 background(255, 0, 0);
 sendLetter = "r";
 }
 else if (widget == greenButton) { //if the green button was clicked
 buttonText="GREEN";
 background(0, 255, 0);
 sendLetter = "g";
 }
 else if (widget == blueButton) { //if the blue button was clicked
 buttonText="BLUE";
 background(0, 0, 255);
 sendLetter = "b";
 }
 else if (widget == offButton) { //if the off button was clicked
 buttonText="OFF";
 background(0);
 sendLetter = "x";
 }
  else if (widget == yeniButton) { //if the off button was clicked
 buttonText="yeni buton";
 background(100,100,100);
 sendLetter = "y";
 }

 byte[] myByte = stringToBytesUTFCustom(sendLetter);
 sendReceiveBT.write(myByte);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to declare the mode (int ) in data on line 14

```
    SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD, TxD);  
int led = 9 ;
int in1Pin = 10;
int in2Pin = 12;
int in3Pin = 11;
int in4Pin = 13;
int data = 100;
```

Comment: yes thanks but the data is just for example . i cant see also 'burak' . i tried a lot also with int . still have problem

Answer (score 0):

I see a fault on the Arduino code - don't think that 23 should be there.

```
if (recvChar=='r') {
    motor.step(300);
    digitalWrite(led,HIGH);23
```

Also - this code requires that you send data from the serial monitor before any Arduino data is sent through bluetooth . Try to echo back the character received by the arduino on this line

```
Serial.print(recvChar);
```

Change it to

```
blueToothSerial.print(recvChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Burak have you solved the problem? I am working with Arduino-Android communication for my project. Try to use `blueToothSerial.write("burak:");`

Also to test your program run some test program. Make some changes with Rx,Tx and you can test it via Arduino Serial Monitor.

```
/*
Pinout:
8 --> BT module Tx
9 --> BT module Rx
*/
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9); // RX, TX

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);


  Serial.println("I am ready to send some stuff!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  while (Serial.available())    
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());

}
```

Also you could try to use ready app from GooglePlay, like "Bluetooth Terminal". If it works with this then look in your code. Please check this for now and later we will be able to continue.